# list of tests concurrently running - in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, hash

I have an hash array with different tests, whats i want to do is to check which test are running concurrently, example of all_tests is

```
all_tests=[{"nameTest"=>"test1", "version"=>"1", "start_date"=>"2022-10-10", "TimeStamp"=>2022-10-11 05:26:02 +0200, "duration"=>311}, {"nameTest"=>"test2", "version"=>"1", "start_date"=>"2022-10-10", "TimeStamp"=>2022-10-11 05:26:01 +0200, "duration"=>4110},{},...]
```

what i did is:

concurrent_tests=[]

```
all_test.each do |the_test| 
      test_start_time = the_test['TimeStamp'].to_i
      test_stop_time = test_start_time + the_test['duration']      
    end
```

**# This will give start and stop time for each tests like:test_start_time= 1665457812 test_stop_time= 1665458646, for each test in an array.**

Now what i want is to only add the tests running concurrently like in the all_test(test1 and test2) are running in concurrent(part of it as test1 started while test2 was still running) so i want to check for this in all_test and add in concurrent_tests. but i dont know how to do that, Can anyone guide on this

Comment: 1) Try to solve the task for the 1st element from `all_tests` only (e.g. "find all tests from the list that are concurrent to the 1st one"), 2) Generalize the solution for the whole list, 3) (optional) Think how to improve it (the 1st "brute-force" version you'll get with will most probably have O(n^2) complexity)

Comment: What's your expected result? A flat array of each test that ran concurrently with some other test at some point? Or do you want to group them so you can see which tests were running concurrently?

Comment: just a flat array, to see which tests were running concurrently at some point